# Java power set through backtrack algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I seem to be having an issue regarding implementing a power set algorithm using backtrack. What I am trying to achieve is rather simple, generate the power set of any given numbers:
Ex. [1 2 3] => [1] [2] [3] ; [1,2] [1,3] [2,3] ; [1,2,3]

My algorithm is using a stack to place the numbers, it adds the numbers to the stack and sends them for calculations. The code is as follows:

```
public int calculatePowerSet(int x, LinkedList<Integer> arr)
{
    int size = 1;
    int nrOfTimes=0;
    int calculate =0;
    boolean goOn=true;
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    int k=0, len = arr.size();
    double temp=0.0f;
    while(size<=len)
    {
        goOn=true;
        stack.push(arr.get(0));
        k = arr.indexOf(stack.peek());
        temp = size;    //ignore these as they are for calculating time
        temp/=len;      //ignore these as they are for calculating time
        temp*=100;      //ignore these as they are for calculating time
        setPowerSetPrecentage((int)temp);
        while(goOn)
        {
            if(isStopProcess())return 0;
            if((k==len)&&(stack.size()==0)) goOn=false;
            else if(stack.size()==size) 
            {
                String sign = "";   
                if((stack.size()%2)==0) sign="+";
                else sign="-";
                calculate =calculateSets(stack.toArray(), sign, calculate, x);
                k = arr.indexOf(stack.pop())+1;
            }
            else if(k==len)
                k = arr.indexOf(stack.pop())+1;
            else
            {
                prepereStack(stack,arr.get(k));
                k++;
            }
        }
        size++;
    }
    return calculate;
}
```

Here is the calculate method:

```
private int calculate(int[] arr2, int x)
{
        int calc=1;

        float rez = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr2.length;i++)
            calc*=arr2[i];
        rez = (float)(x/calc);
        calc = (int) (rez+0.5d);
        return calc;
}
```

The code seems to be working perfectly for all numbers bellow 20, but after that i seem to be getting wrong results. I cannot check manually through the numbers as there are hundreds of combinations. For example for one input of 25 numbers i should get a result of 1229, instead i get 1249. I am not sure what i am missing as i think the algorithm should be working in theory, so if anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

Comment: "for one input of 25 numbers i should get a result of 1229" ? The size of the power-set of 25 different items is `2^25` which is >> 1229. Care to explain?

Comment: Yes the number itself is derived from a calculation that i am performing after the power set has been concluded... for example each combination of the numbers will be divided by a number x. However, the issue is still the generation of the power set.

Comment: So to summarise, your calculation *will* be incorrect since you are unable to generate the power set correctly anyway? What is your proof that 1229 is correct and not 1249?

Comment: Follow this blog to generate the power set properly : http://jvalentino.blogspot.co.uk/2007/02/shortcut-to-calculating-power-set-using.html

Comment: I.K.: Yes that is correct, the number is wrong since the power set is incorrectly generated. I know that the number is 1229 since the whole calculation that i am trying to perform is taken from Legendre formula, which has at it's base the power set generation. I have tested the same number on a different algorithm, which is based on recursion using lists and sublists, and the answer given there is correct. Furthermore, the mathematical explanation is taken from a book which also displays the proper result as 1229

Comment: @DanutNiculae, that's good enough for me. Then just follow the blog to generate the power set correctly. If you get stuck then send us another message. Note for us to receive a message directly you must prepend our ID with the ampersand symbol.

Comment: @DanutNiculae I can't see where the `calculate` method is called. I can only see `calculateSets` which you have not provided the definition for.

Comment: @I.K. that algorithm is efficient and clever but not simple. I would think OP would be better off with something more obvious even if less efficient.

Comment: @sprinter The  calculateSets method just differentiates between a subtraction or an addition and calls the calculate method.

Comment: @I.K. I will try to implement the algorithm in the blog you have provided me, thank you :) but somehow i would still like to keep the backtracking algorithm as it is easier to manipulate later on

Comment: Another comment: using variable names such as "x", "k", "calculate" and "temp" makes it harder to understand your code. Consider providing better names so that it'll be easier to understand what a variable represents and what a method is supposed to do. As for the "above 20" issue, just an idea: since you're using integers you might be overflowing somewhere in your calculations. Though MAX_INT is 2^31-1 so theoretically it doesn't suppose to happen for ~20 items. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend separating out the generation of the power sets from your calculation. While there are some very efficient algorithms for generating power sets I would suggest keeping it quite simple until you need the efficiency.

```
private void forEachSet(List<Integer> currentSet, List<Integer> rest) {
    if (rest.isEmpty()) {
        process(currentSet);
    } else {
        Integer nextInt = rest.remove(0);
        forEachSet(currentSet, rest);
        currentSet.add(nextInt);
        forEachSet(currentSet, rest);
        current.remove(nextInt);
        rest.add(nextInt);
    }
}

public forEachSet(List<Integer> set) {
    forEachSet(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(set));
}
```

Comment: While the solution is a good one, I will have problems with sets within sets, due to the fact that i am working with large numbers. If i try to implement something in that nature, I will get Heap error, since it runs out of space in the memory. This is why i chose to work with Stacks and keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: @DanutNiculae I'm not sure I understand your comment. My solution doesn't have sets within sets: it just maintains two lists: the current one and the rest. There's nothing less efficient about lists than stacks. Really the main difference is that my solution uses recursion to maintain state.